# Raspberry Pi 4 - BCM2835 Library - SPI1 - data mode 1

Tags: hardware, pi-4, spi, c, raspi-config

I use the BCM2835 library to communicate in SPI with an ADC. The SPI0 interface is already used by a touch screen (https://www.pi-shop.ch/pitft-plus-480x320-3-5-tft-touchscreen-fuer-raspberry-pi-model-a-b-pi-2-pi-3)

So I have to use the SPI1 which is represented (if I understood correctly) by the functions "BCM2835_aux_spi_XXX" (C language) .

My problem is that my ADC works in mode 1 (CPOL=0, SPHA=1), and there is no function to configure the SPI in this mode.

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work.

The Pi's aux SPI device only works in modes 0 and 2.